# The randomize transform operator yields the same result every time it's called

Tags: python, scripting, random

I'm trying to add a little more randomization to the randomize transform modifier in Blender. I want to randomize the location settings to produce different results in each image. But the random functions (`random.randint (a,b)`) don't seem to work within the randomize transform modifier. Below is a very basic example of my code. For some reason, it produces the same results every time. The random code below works fine with everything else, but it doesn't work at all within the randomize transform modifier. Any ideas?

```
import bpy
import random
import math

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

so=bpy.context.active_object

mod_outline = so.modifiers.new ("outline", 'WIREFRAME')
mod_outline.thickness = 0.1
bpy.context.object.modifiers["outline"].offset = -1

for i in range (500):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

num1 = random.randint(0, 5)
num2 = random.randint(0, 5)
num3 = random.randint(0, 5)

bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform(loc=(num1, num2, num3))
```

Comment: There is no such thing as random in computers. Here's a good explanation as to why and the workaround solutions to create a pseudo-random value https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/. you need to initialize a seed value like for example `random.seed(time.time())`

Answer (score 3):

bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform() operator randomises values on its own. You don't need to input random values for it to work. If you want more or different kind of randomisation, just write a new operator that would transform objects based on your desired kind of randomness.

You can find a template for an operator in the Text Editor's Templates -> Python menu:
[image]

You already use [Python's random library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) Have a look at changing seed value for randomisation in it's documentation if you face a problem that it generates the same values.
And it's quite easy to change location of selected objects(or any other kind of list of objects) in a loop:

```
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    o.location = ...
```

So you can put all of this together any way you wish.

Comment: I don't think it's worth re-implementing default operators as is but indeed it might be beneficial if they'd like to add custom functionality. Here's a link to the the operator logic FWIW https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/object_randomize_transform.py#L7-L71

Comment: I did not mean to suggest to re-implement the default one. I would leave it alone, just make a new one that does what is needed. I don't understand how the randomness of the randomize_transform() operator is not 'random enough' in the first place to be honest. It's just random. But if one needed some other kind of random distribution then making it from  scratch in another operator will be a better way for sure because you can use all the stuff in Python's random library or even some other type of generating randomness in that case.

Comment: Agreed :) In this case the call to the operator missed the `random_seed` argument which is by default set to 0 to make the operator non-deterministic

Comment: I know it seems silly to add randomization to a randomization tool, but i'm running multiple outputs. Loc = (2, 2, 2) spreads everything out randomly into the shape of a cube every time. (0, 2, 2,) spreads everything out randomly across the y and z axis, basically in the shape of a square. And so on. All the way down to (0, 0, 0) which wont do anything at all. So if I run it 100 times, many outputs will look much different in scale. That is my goal. I just needed to add the random seed to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

The [Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/randomize.html) operator take a `random_seed` argument, by default set to 0. Different calls to this operator with default arguments will yield the same result. The random seed must be between 0 and 10000 [for some reason](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=randomize_transform#bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform).

Try

```
bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform(
    loc=(num1, num2, num3), 
    random_seed=random.randint(0, 10000)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked.